# single file reader/multiple consumer model: good idea for multithreaded program?

Tags: multithreading, io, consumer, producer

I have a simple task that is easily parallelizable.  Basically, the same operation must be performed repeatedly on each line of a (large, several Gb) input file.  While I've made a multithreaded version of this, I noticed my I/O was the bottleneck.   I decided to build a utility class that involves a single "file reader" thread that simply goes and reads straight ahead as fast as it can into a circular buffer.  Then, multiple consumers can call this class and get their 'next line'.  Given n threads, each thread i's starting line is line i in the file, and each subsequent line for that thread is found by adding n.   It turns out that locks are not needed for this, a couple key atomic ops are enough to preserve invariants.

I've tested the code and it seems faster, but upon second thought, I'm not sure why.  Wouldn't it be just as fast to divide the large file into n input files ( you can 'seek' ahead into the same file to achieve the same thing, minimal preprocessing ), and then have each process simply call iostream::readLine on its own chunk?  ( since iostream reads into its own buffer as well ).   It doesn't seem that sharing a single buffer amongst multiple threads has any inherent advantage, since the workers are not actually operating on the same lines of data.  Plus, there's no good way I don't think to parallelize so that they do work on the same lines.   I just want to understand the performance gain I'm seeing, and know whether it is 'flukey' or scalable/reproducible across platforms...

Comment: Anything other than sequential file reading will do more harm than good, especially with large files that would require actual mechanical disk operations to 'really' read data that is not in the disk/driver cache.  I'm not so sure about your single circular buffer design.  Inter-thread comms for single text lines is not going to be very efficient - too many atomic ops and the read thread is saddled with parsing lines when it should be filling buffer/s.  I would probably go with a pool of much larger buffer instances.

Answer (score 0):

When you are I/O limited, you can get a good speedup by using two threads, one reading the file, second doing the processing. This way the reading will never wait for processing (expect for the very last line) and you will be doing reading 100 %.

The buffer should be large enough to give the consumer thread enough work in one go, which most often means it should consist of multiple lines (I would recommend at least 4000 characters, but probably even more). This will prevent thread context switching cost to be impractically high.

Single threaded:

- read 1
- process 1
- read 2
- process  2
- read 3
- process 3

Double threaded:

- read 1
- process 1/read 2
- process  2/read 3
- process 3

On some platforms you can get the same speedup also without threads, using overlapped I/O, but using threads can be often clearer.

Using more than one consumer thread will bring no benefit as long as you are really I/O bound.

Comment: I have found this as well..but doesn't iostream have a buffer of its own?  Why is this a speed up?

Comment: When working single threaded, the buffer needs to be processed and only then a next buffer is read. If some read X needs a new data, it needs to wait until the complete new buffer is read. There is no "speculative read ahead" performed by the stream. When you do the threading, the processing is done in parallel to reading next buffer.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, there are at least two resources that your program competes for, the CPU and the harddisk. In a single-threaded approach, you request data then wait with an idle CPU for the HD to deliver it. Then, you handle the data, while the HD is idle. This is bad, because one of the two resources is always idle. This changes a bit if you have multiple CPUs or multiple HDs. Also, in some cases the memory bandwidth (i.e. the RAM connection) is also a limiting resource.

Now, your solution is right, you use one thread to keep the HD busy. If this threads blocks waiting for the HD, the OS just switches to a different thread that handles some data. If it doesn't have any data, it will wait for some. That way, CPU and HD will work in parallel, at least some of the time, increasing the overall throughput. Note that you can't increase the throughput with more than two threads, unless you also have multiple CPUs and the CPU is the limiting factor and not the HD. If you are writing back some data, too, you could improve performance with a third thread that writes to a second harddisk. Otherwise, you don't get any advantage from more threads.